# ipod style drilldown menu with ajax loading childrens

Tags: jquery

I'd like to implement a Drill Down Menu using [this iPod-styled jQuery drill down plugin](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/) - 
[see examples](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/menus/ipod.php)

It works well with static content and `ul > li` items, but I'd like to be able to load the child menus using Ajax.

For example, given some initial markup like:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="some">some content</a>
    <ul class='childrenContent'/>
  </li>
</ul>`
```

When I click `.some`, additional content should be loaded into `.childrenContent`. This should happen for all nested menus.

Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to get this to work - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with event delegation: http://api.jquery.com/on/  Somewhere in the menu source code, you need to change `.click()` to `.on('click',`

Answer (score 0):

As @DevlshOne mentions, understanding event delegation will definitely help you here. [Check out the `.on()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for some understanding of the issue. Essentially, you want to bind an event to an element which doesn't exist when you create your page.

To get around this, you bind the click event to an element which **does** exist on page load, and then using the following jQuery method, you check to see whether the event has bubbled up through the given element (in this case `.some`).

```
$("#mydrilldown").on("click", ".some", loadContent);
```

So the breakdown would be "when I click on `#mydrilldown`, check to see if we've bubbled through `.some`, and if we have, run `loadContent`. I've not attempted to create `loadContent`, as there's no need, but that function should do all the loading of the nested list, and creating the nested `.some` element in your case.